# Show data of table using WP 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, sql-server-ce-3.5

How can i create gridview drillthrough table on windows phone 8?
I have a tables product `(id,name,actual)`  on sql server compact 3.5.
 i would like to show this table on the emulator and add new product from it

Comment: What do you mean "show the table"?

Comment: i have table on my database contains id,name ,age email  i like to show it on the emulator

Comment: Have you taken a look at the "Windows Phone Databound App" project in VS? Have you tried [this link](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+phone+sqlce&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=windows+phone+sqlce&sc=4-19&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=2084999466b34a2abaa27dae27b7f23e)?

Comment: i like to diplay data and edit it